# Python dictionary does not get sorted by "Res" key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries which looks something like that:

```
comps = [('7', {'Name': 'Cristiano', 'Surname': 'Ronaldo', 'Res': 152.329937}), ...
```

and when i try this:

```
sorted_comps = sorted(comps.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]['Res'])
```

it gives me  this:

```
KeyError: 'Res'
```

Even tho with both of other Keywords: Name\Surname it sorts just fine and I can even reverse it if I want to

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete example (no `...`), also this is not a dictionary but a list of tuples, with dictionaries as some of the items.

Comment: Somewhere in the `...` section, there is tuple with a dict with no `"Res"` in it.

Comment: @mozway it says <class 'dict'> when i use 'code' type(comps) 'code'

Comment: You can change `x[1]['Res']` to `x[1].get('Res', 0)` this will put all the ones with no Res at the start (it “assumes” they’re 0)

Comment: @reeqo The `comps` in your actual code must be different to the one you posted here - which is a list because it starts with `[`

Comment: Did you notice the AttributeError when you tried running your code against the data shown in the question? That will happen because a Python list does not have a *items()* attribute

Comment: @reeqo "*it says <class 'dict'>*" -> then your example here is not representative

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a key error occurs when you are trying to look up a key in a dictionary and this does not exist. It might be due to an tuple entry in `comps` that does not have `Res` as key in index 1 of the tuple. Furthermore, `comps`, as pointed out in the comments, is a list, thus you should treat it as a list. You cannot state `comps.items()`, since `list` doesn't have an attribute `items`. You can just use `comps` in your sorting. For example as a minimal example:

```py
comps = [('A', {'Res': 1}),('B', {'Res': 4}),('C', {'Res': 3}),('D', {'Res': 2})]
sorted(comps, key=lambda x:x[1]['Res'])
>>> [('A', {'Res': 1}), ('D', {'Res': 2}), ('C', {'Res': 3}), ('B', {'Res': 4})]
```